# Read Holding Register bit in Python using pymodbus lib

Tags: python, pymodbus

Kindly suggest which function we can use to read single bit of holding register in python.
im communicating modbus tcp protocol using python pymodubs library.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean or show and example of what you wish to achieve ?

Comment: Hello D.L.. Thanks for your concern. my issue is solved by using below code

Comment: value1 = client.read_holding_registers(101, 1)
bins = value1.registers[0]
print(bin(bins))